# What member information is shared through the Atomic FI External App Integration?

Tags: banno-digital-toolkit

For the External Application we have configured for Atomic FI (Direct Deposit), can you share the details of what information is passed from Banno to Atomic? In addition to what's passed over, I'm also curious if Banno is generating/creating a unique Banno ID for each member that is sent to Atomic, that allows our employees to go through Atomic's portal to link back to the member's Banno profile. Thank you!

We have the integration built, and in use. It's working properly, but we don't know what data is being shared with the vendor.

Answer (score 0):

### Short answer

You'll need to ask the folks at [Atomic FI](https://atomic.financial/) for info about what they specifically use from the Digital Toolkit for their plugin and how they use it. Here's some info that'll help you have that discussion with them (or any 3rd party developer).

### Authentication Framework

There's a difference in what any 3rd party developer might have access to via an *Identity Token* and what they might have access to via an *Access Token*. The general usage of Identity Tokens and Access Tokens is described in the [Authentication Framework / Tokens](https://jackhenry.dev/open-api-docs/authentication-framework/overview/tokens/) page.

The Identity Token has authenticated information about the user, and that information is presented in the form of *claims*. The [Authentication Framework / OpenID Connect and OAuth 2.0](https://jackhenry.dev/open-api-docs/authentication-framework/overview/openidconnectoauth/) page lists all of the possible claims which can appear in the Identity Token.

- Some of those claims are returned, if requested by the 3rd party app, as part of being an OpenID Connect-compatible provider (which Banno's API is, in fact).
- Some of those claims are *Publicly Available Claims* which may be requested by any 3rd party app.
- The potentially sensitive claims are in the *Restricted Claims* category. A 3rd party app could request those claims, but they won't actually receive the data unless an admin at the financial institution has configured that claim to be enabled in the [External Application](https://jackhenry.dev/open-api-docs/plugins/architecture/externalapplications/).

You'll want to make sure to ask the 3rd party developer for the set of claims they're requesting to appear in the Identity Token.

The Access Token provides authorized access to the user's financial data (see the Consumer API below).

### Consumer API

Each Consumer API endpoint defines the OAuth *scope* which must be in the Access Token in order to perform that endpoint's given function/operation.

For example, accessing the [Consumer API / Accounts](https://jackhenry.dev/open-api-docs/consumer-api/api-reference/v0/accounts/details/) data can vary.

If the 3rd party developer has included the `https://api.banno.com/consumer/auth/accounts.readonly` scope in their authorization request, then they can *read* the accounts information via the `GET /users/{userId}/accounts` endpoint since that's one of the scopes defined as a requirement in the definition of that endpoint.

If the 3rd party developer then wanted to get the unmasked account number from the `GET /users/{userId}/accounts/{accountId}/number`, then they would need a *different* scope to be included in their authorization request (specifically, `https://api.banno.com/consumer/auth/accounts.unmaskednumber.readonly`) otherwise they won't be able to use that endpoint.

You'll want to make sure to ask the 3rd party developer for the set of scopes they're requesting for access in the Access Token.

### Plugin Framework

The Plugin Framework uses the Authentication Framework to handle authentication (as described above). It's common (but not required) for plugins to use the Consumer API (as described above).

It's worth noting that the Plugin Framework has its own [Restrictions](https://jackhenry.dev/open-api-docs/plugins/architecture/restrictions/) on how a plugin operates within the context of Banno's Dashboard UI and how topics such as [cookies, same-origin policy, etc](https://jackhenry.dev/open-api-docs/plugins/overview/authentication/) are handled.

Comment: Thank you, Jaime! This gives me some talking points to go back to Atomic FI with. I will update this thread once I have additional info back from them.